# Does MySQL store point datatypes as LAT LNG or LNG LAT?

Tags: mysql, spatial

I'm used to seeing location format as latitude followed by longitude, but using libraries, I believe I understand MySQL to store it as `POINT(LNG LAT)`, the reverse order. Is my library in the wrong, or is this the actual format? I can't seem to find this detail in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: You can probably give this a read:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Constructor Syntax

Looking up the [spatial function reference,](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point) you'll see

```
Point(x, y)
Constructs a Point using its coordinates
```

This isn't entirely correct. All GIS implementations must do `(x,y)` for projected coordinates which is  `(long,lat)`. But, on geodidic cordinate systems there is some disagreement about what to do. MySQL (and SQL Server) do `(lat,long)` but PostGIS maintains `(long,lat)` everywhere.

This is touched on in the [spec *OpenGIS®
Implementation Standard for Geographic
information - Simple feature access - Part 2: SQL option*](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25354),

> - For geodetic CRSs having an ellipsoidal 2-D coordinate system, the two-dimensional ellipsoidal coordinate system axes are geodetic latitude, positive northwards, and geodetic longitude, positive eastwards. Axis direction shall be ‘north’ and ‘east’ respectively.
> - For geodetic CRSs having a three-dimensional ellipsoidal coordinate system, the name and abbreviation of the horizontal axes in a WKT string shall follow the requirements in (ii). The vertical axis name shall be ‘ellipsoidal height’; the vertical axis abbreviation shall be ‘h’ and should be included when abbreviations for the horizontal axes are included.

**Note the above words are found verbatim in [Geographic information - Well-known text representation of coordinate reference systems](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-063r5/12-063r5.html#113)**

Even [as far back as the 1.1 spec,](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=829)

> A spatial reference system, also referred to as a coordinate system, is a **geographic (latitude-longitude)**, a projected (X,Y), or a geocentric (X,Y,Z) coordinate system.

That said, it seems PostGIS and Oracle and many third party libraries maintain `(x,y,[z])` for all types of points. This is in violation of the spec for WKT, but is a pretty common convention. For example [GeoJSON also does this,](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.2)

> Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for projected
> coordinates, longitude, and latitude for geographic coordinates)

And, (lat,long) ordering is explicitly defined by [EPSG for SRSID 4326,](http://epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326).

> A 2D or 3D coordinate system in which position is specified by geodetic latitude, geodetic longitude and (in the three-dimensional case) ellipsoidal height, used in Geographic CRSs.

You may also consider checking out [Paul Ramsey's (Captain PostGIS) blog on this subject entitled, *"Let's Call the Whole Thing Off"*](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2007/12/lets-call-whole-thing-off.html)

## Nicities

As a special note, MySQL brings two new functions to the mix,

- [`ST_Longitude()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-longitude)
- [`ST_Latitude()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-latitude)

These functions stand aside from `ST_X()`, and `ST_Y()` and **require** a geographic SRS or they throw an exception and error.

## Storage

From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-data-formats.html)

> Internally, MySQL stores geometry values in a format that is not identical to either WKT or WKB format. (Internal format is like WKB but with an initial 4 bytes to indicate the SRID.)

[Storing is defined here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkb-format).

```
Table 11.1 WKB Components Example

Component       Size    Value
Byte order      1 byte  01
WKB type        4 bytes 01000000
X coordinate    8 bytes 000000000000F03F
Y coordinate    8 bytes 000000000000F0BF
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check the order is passing out of range latitude:

```
SELECT ST_Longitude(ST_SRID(POINT(45, 160), 4326));
```

Gives ERROR 3732 (22S03): A parameter of function st_srid contains a geometry with latitude 160.000000, which is out of range. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000];

Beware that the order may change depending on the functions you use :

```
SELECT ST_Longitude(ST_SRID(POINT(45, 90), 4326));
SELECT ST_Longitude(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(45 90)', 4326));
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 uses the default lat-lon order which can be customized by an additional parameter `'axis-order=long-lat'` to parse WKT:

```
mysql> set @loc = ST_GeomFromText('Point(47 -122)', 4326);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ST_Longitude(@loc), ST_Latitude(@loc);
+---------------------+-------------------+
| ST_Longitude(@loc)  | ST_Latitude(@loc) |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| -122.00000000000001 |                47 |
+---------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @loc = ST_GeomFromText('Point(-122 47)', 4326, 'axis-order=long-lat');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ST_Longitude(@loc), ST_Latitude(@loc);
+---------------------+-------------------+
| ST_Longitude(@loc)  | ST_Latitude(@loc) |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| -122.00000000000001 |                47 |
+---------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but uses lon-lat order in the constructor:

```
mysql> set @loc = ST_SRID(Point(-122, 47), 4326);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ST_Longitude(@loc), ST_Latitude(@loc);
+---------------------+-------------------+
| ST_Longitude(@loc)  | ST_Latitude(@loc) |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| -122.00000000000001 |                47 |
+---------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```