# How do I dump spatial types, like point, with their SRIDs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spatial, geometry

I am testing the point data type on Mysq 5.7 below is my java insert query.

```
String insertQuery1 ="INSERT INTO gtest3 SET " +
      "gDateTime='2017-07-16 01:00:00'"+
      ",vehicleID=1"+   
      ",alarmTypeID=1"+
      ",latlong=Point("+floatLatitude+","+floatLongitude+")";
```

The values are inserted accordingly but when I got to the row it shows something like `GEOMETERY -25B` but when I press to edit it show me this `'POINT(5.19878 100.492)',0` . I would like is this correct with the extra 0 at the back. Can this values be used for later spatial functions.

Comment: "when I press to edit it show me this 'POINT(5.19878 100.492)',0 " What are you pressing edit in?

Comment: @EvanCaroll I am using myphpadmin gui to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The `0` in that context is the SRID. Unlike in PostgreSQL, you don't have a method of setting that on a point. You will in [version 8 of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8543). For the purposes of calculation, it's assumed to be `0` on everything and this is horrible. There is likely to be substantial breakage when they fix this.

> In MySQL, all computations are done assuming SRID 0, regardless of the actual SRID value. SRID 0 represents an infinite flat Cartesian plane with no units assigned to its axes. In the future, computations may use the specified SRID values. To ensure SRID 0 behavior, create geometry values using SRID 0. SRID 0 is the default for new geometry values if no SRID is specified. [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-function-argument-handling.html)

So the SRID will *almost* always be 0 because

- it doesn't yet matter
- There is no [SRID mutator](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8543) so you have to construct with `ST_PointFromText`. So the SRID will always be `0` if you construct with a point

That said, to get the SRID (future-safe) in the format provided above, you need to do this

```
SELECT CONCAT(ST_AsText(x), ',', ST_SRID(x))
FROM ( SELECT POINT(0,0) AS x ) AS t;

+---------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(ST_AsText(x), ',', ST_SRID(x)) |
+---------------------------------------+
| POINT(1 1),0                          |
+---------------------------------------+
```

This will show differently if your SRID is not 0.

```
SELECT CONCAT(ST_AsText(x), ',', ST_SRID(x))
FROM ( SELECT ST_PointFromText('POINT(1 1)',4326) AS x ) AS t;

+---------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(ST_AsText(x), ',', ST_SRID(x)) |
+---------------------------------------+
| POINT(1 1),4326                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Compare that to PostgreSQL,

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(x)
FROM ( VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1,1),4326)) ) AS t(x);
      st_asewkt       
----------------------
 SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)
(1 row)
```

## Update

Taking a look at your query, there is one glaring mistake in that you do `(latitude,longitude)` this [should be `(longitude,latitude)`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182136/does-mysql-store-point-datatypes-as-lat-lng-or-lng-lat/182626#182626)

> So to be safe is my existing insert query is acceptable or should I add the SRID value now.

I would add the SRID value now, but not because your existing query "isn't safe". Only because you're not using placeholders and you're stringifying everything anyway.

```
",latlong=Point("+floatLatitude+","+floatLongitude+")";
```

Should be

```
",latlong=ST_PointFromText(POINT("+floatLongitude+" "+floatLatitude+"), 4326)";
```

Where 4326 is the SRID of your data..

But again, **MySQL doesn't take into consideration SRID yet** so be aware.

## Objective facts

MySQL and MariaDB have *horrible* spatial support. Migrate to PostgreSQL and PostGIS, if possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64718/discussion-on-answer-by-evan-carroll-how-do-i-dump-spatial-types-like-point-wi).