# Is INSERT INTO ... SET standard SQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mariadb, insert, sql-standard

I'm just wondering if [this syntax](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/182519/2639) is standard or where it comes from?

For example

```
INSERT INTO gtest3 SET gDateTime='2017-07-16 01:00:00'
```

You can see it [documented in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) but PostgreSQL [does not support it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a MySQL extension, the SQL 2011 spec defines the insert grammar as,

```
<insert statement> ::=
INSERT INTO <insertion target> <insert columns and source>
14

<insertion target> ::=
<table name>

<insert columns and source> ::=
<from subquery>
| <from constructor>
| <from default>

<from subquery> ::=
[ <left paren> <insert column list> <right paren> ]
[ <override clause> ]
<query expression>

<from constructor> ::=
[ <left paren> <insert column list> <right paren> ]
[ <override clause> ]
<contextually typed table value constructor>

<override clause> ::=
OVERRIDING USER VALUE
| OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE

<from default> ::=
DEFAULT VALUES

<insert column list> ::=
<column name list>
```

You can see this [talked about on the Pg Lists](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/SET-syntax-in-INSERT-td2014033.html)

Comment: Interesting - , and considering how UPDATE works, it makes sense and everything.

Comment: @RDFozz yea, truth be told, I don't find it to be particularly offensive. It's not a bad extension on SQL. Even a blind squirrel finds a nut once in a while, etc.

Comment: Recently I was writing long INSERT..SELECTs, trying to check the columns aligned, wishing I had `insert T1 (col1 = t.cola, col2 = t.colx) from table2 as t`

Comment: @MichaelGreen like I said, definitely not MySQL's worst idea. I admitted it!