# Data truncation on spatial query after updating from MySql 5.7 to 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, spatial, srid

I have the following table:

```sql
create table places
(
    id bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    position point SRID 4326 not null
);

create spatial index position
    on places (position);

-- Some test data
insert into places (position)
values
    (st_srid(POINT(40.67 -73.94))),
    (st_srid(POINT(38.895 -77.036666666))),
    (st_srid(POINT(37.7775 -122.416388888))),
    (st_srid(POINT(52.516666666 13.383333333))),
    (st_srid(POINT(34.05223 -118.24368))),
    (st_srid(POINT(46.94798 7.44743))),
    (st_srid(POINT(46.2 6.15))),
    (st_srid(POINT(47.378611111 8.54))),
    (st_srid(POINT(47.560555555 7.590555555)));
```

on a MySql 8.0 database. The data is imported from a 5.7 database (the SRID is set to 4326 on every row of the `position` column of the 5.7 database as well).

I'm aware that from 5.7 to 8.0, [X and Y on geometry objects for SRID 4326 got swapped](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242004/183351), so that points are now "latitude, longitude", so when I imported the data I applied `ST_SwapXY()` on `position`. (Note that I also tried the query below on an identical table where I had not performed this step.)

When I try to run a query similar to the following:

```sql
SET @lon = 7.4653;
SET @lat = 51.5136;
SELECT
p.id,
ST_Distance_Sphere(p.position, ST_SRID(POINT(@lat, @lon), 4326)) AS distance,
ST_AsText(p.position)
FROM (
    SELECT id, position
    FROM places
    WHERE MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('Polygon((',
        @lat -3.0, ' ', @lon -3.0, ', ',
        @lat +3.0, ' ', @lon -3.0, ', ',
        @lat +3.0, ' ', @lon +3.0, ', ',
        @lat -3.0, ' ', @lon +3.0, ', ',
        @lat -3.0, ' ', @lon -3.0, '))'), 4326),
        position)
    OR position = ST_SRID(POINT(0.0, 0.0), 4326)
    LIMIT 10000
) p
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

I get the following error:

`[22001][3732] Data truncation: A parameter of function mbrcontains contains a geometry with latitude -122.416389, which is out of range. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].`

This also happens if I swap all `@lat`s with `@lon`s in the `MBRContains()` call.

Have I missed some other step I should have taken when importing the data? Is there something I' m not considering? **How do I make the query work?**

Comment: can you add some data t your table, where the error occurs, t make a [mre]

Comment: To get closer to a "square" for the bounding box, adjust:  `@lon - 3.0/cos(radians(@lat))`, etc.

Comment: The test on [0,0] seems 'wrong'.

Comment: I test on 0,0 because some data points don't have a position, but I couldn't keep nulls in the `position` column or the spatial index would not work.

Comment: @nbk I added a few example records.

Comment: @RickJames is that to account for the curvature of the Earth?

Comment: i ran your code, but it throws other errors https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/20

Comment: @nbk apologies, I had a stray comma in the schema declaration. However, I can't find what's wrong with the query, and after solving the issue (see my own answer below) it runs well on my database. Maybe db-fiddle doesn't support 8.0 spatial functions? I don't really have a clue.

Comment: i naswer a lot of spacial queistions and i had never a problem.  i will have a look at it

Comment: @theberzi - Yes.  The longitude lines are closer together near the poles, hence "3.0" needs to be increased to account for it.  Dividing by COS(lat) is a good first approximation (except very close to poles).  More discussion of "find nearest":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the problem.

When MySQL 8.0 inverted latitude and longitude, it didn't invert the structure of the geometry itself, but **only the representation in spatial functions**.

I suppose this information is available somewhere in the documentation, but I personally wasn't able to find anything that clearly states that the change from 5.7 to 8.0 only affected spatial functions and the *textual representation* of points, and not points themselves. Great job, Oracle. :/

So in short the solution is to simply use a table that does *not* swap x and y, and instead swap x and y everywhere in the query.

**EDIT:** furthermore, the `distance` column of the query yields incorrect results using the order `POINT(@lat, @lon)`. It yields correct results by using `POINT(@lon, @lat)`, which must mean the inversion of latitude and longitude must not be taken into account when defining points, *unless the definition passes through a `ST_` or `MBR` function*.